# Vala for Windows: Install WebKit

Tags: linux, windows, webkit, gtk, vala

A few months ago I installed Vala for Windows and started developing GTK-applications. I've did this with the "MSYS2"-project and the standart installer. So now: My question is, how it is possible to install the WebKit in my Vala for Windows installation. I tried to download it via pacman with the MSYS2-console but a few errors appeared. Next, I tried to manually add the webkit-stuff to my Vala for Windows installation directory. But I always get the error "fatal error: webkit/webkit.h: No such file or directory" when I use the right compile command.

Does someone know a possibility to install WebKit in Vala for Windows?

Thank you!

PS: Compiling with the same command and installed WebKit via my Ubuntu installation worked like a charm.

Comment: did you install both runtime and devel packages?

Comment: Are you talking about the MSYS2 console?